# link to my facebook page from facebook like box plug-in not displaying posts

Tags: facebook, plugins

What do I do to make the link to my facebook account  display the facebook like box?

I just copied & pasted html code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

First, the plug-in does work when I copy & paste that sample code to my test page.

See: net-gal.com/fbTest2.html

So it is isolated to the link to my facebook page.

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/ginger.lindbergh" data-width="292" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="true"></div>
```

See: net-gal.com/fbTest.html

I also tried to use my numeric facebook id:

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/1520846863" data-width="292" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="true"></div>
```

See: net-gal.com/fbTest3.html

Neither above pulled in the like box.

My facebook security settings allow plug-in access.  While I have only 1 test post today on my fb page, it should still pull that up.

Can the facebook like box work properly on a simple facebook page or does it have to be  a fan page or something special?  Does anyone know why it does not display my like box and yet displays the sample?

***Sorry but I am too new to post more than 2 links on this page.

By the way, I have searched many, many posts here and through google search and have not found an answer that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Right from the top of the docs page you linked to:

> *“The Like Box is a social plugin that enables **Facebook Page** owners to attract and gain Likes from their own website.”*

You are trying to display the Like Box for a *personal profile* on Facebook, but it can not be used this way.

Comment: Thank you so much - that solves it!  What is the difference between a personal profile and a facebook page?

Comment: Never mind I already checked on google and found the difference is a personal and business account each having different properties and functions.  Thank you again for your help.